# Как правильно сжимать картинки (php)?

Tags: php

Есть картинки, которые загружаются в интернет-магазин через обычный массив $_FILE. Вопрос: как правильно сжать картинки без потери качества и сделать их ресайз на php? Какие есть классы для работы с картинками? Гугл выдает много всякого трэша

Comment: Вопрос - найди класс?

Comment: @Visman просто прошу поделиться каким-либо вариантом, поскольку этих классов дофига, а многие из них очень неудобны. Вроде в этом и смысл такого сообщества

Answer (score 0):

Банально ищите на гитхабе по кол-ву звезд, находите такие, которые удобны вам по наличию/функционалу методов. Удобные на мой взгляд:

[Intervention/image](https://github.com/Intervention/image)

```
// open an image file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// resize image instance
$img->resize(320, 240);

// insert a watermark
$img->insert('public/watermark.png');

// save image in desired format
$img->save('public/bar.jpg');
```

[avalanche123/Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine)

```
$imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
// or
$imagine = new Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
// or
$imagine = new Imagine\Gmagick\Imagine();

$size    = new Imagine\Image\Box(40, 40);

$mode    = Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;
// or
$mode    = Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND;

$imagine->open('/path/to/large_image.jpg')
    ->thumbnail($size, $mode)
    ->save('/path/to/thumbnail.png')
;
```

И другие....

Comment: Вопрос: зачем? Если это можно самому написать за час?

Comment: @DaemonHK, что зачем? этот вопрос к тс. По-вашему 5 вопросов - 5 часов написания кода, а так я могу за 10 минут пользоваться 5-ю фреймворками, который постоянно обновляется и улучшается, на которые вы бы потом еще потратили 25 часов.